# Store/Fetch text with emoji Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Please help me on it: I've a textbox in which user is able to type text like `Hi, This is test of emoji ☢️` and I've to save this record in table. Also once I pull this record from table and showing to client end must show same along with emoji. I've created column type as nvarchar(450) with SQL server 2014 database. **I'm sending this text using API to stored procedure.**

Currently I'm passing text as `Hi, This is test of emoji ☢️` then storing in DB as `Hi, This is test of emoji ??`

***This is my stored proc:***

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SP_Save_Not_StatsTrans] @Not_Content nvarchar(max), @PublishedOn datetime
as
begin
insert into Tb_Notifications(ObjectUid, Not_Content,PublishedOn) values
(NEWID(),@Not_Content,@PublishedOn)
end
```

Comment: You might wanna include your stored procedure code, as well as how you call it

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be interested to see your insert statement. Emojis are Unicode so you need an 'N' in front of the string you're inserting.

- (N'this is a test ☢️') instead of ('this is a test ☢️')

This works: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8376OkCd)

```
INSERT INTO table_(col) VALUES (N'this is a test ☢️');

SELECT * FROM table_;
```

returns

```
-------------------
|col               |
--------------------
|this is a test ☢️|
```

Comment: thanks for your response. By calling this way `exec [SP_Save_Not_StatsTrans] N'this is a test ☢️','2013-03-01'` its storing in DB and showing at client end perfectly. Now, I;ve call this stored propc from C# end so how we've to pass "N'this is a test ☢️'"? please guide me

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. With @Not_Content being an nvarchar, I believe your SQL is correct. I think your issue is your C# is not passing the string as unicode. Unfortunately, I can't help you there. I'm not a C# guy.

Comment: Thanks lots, I've fixed this. Issue was when I called this procedure need to set parameter type as nvarchar. Thanks for this help